# How to apply a Grid layout to nested child elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I've been scratching my head over this one for a few days now. I'm trying to create a `UserControl`(s) that will allow me to simplify the process of creating I/O forms. In many forms I need something with a structure such as this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition>          
      ...
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="..."/>
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="..."/>

   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="..."/>
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="..."/>

   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="..."/>
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="..."/>
   ...

<Grid>
```

What I'd like to write is something like this:

```
<mycontrols:ContainerControl>
   <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}">
   <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}">
   <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}">
   <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}">
</mycontrols:ContainerControl>
```

The `RowControl`'s XAML would simply be a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox` style to my liking:

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

As I understand there are a few issues with this:

1.- In order that an element is affected by the grid layout, it has to be an immediate child of that Grid.

2.- The number of rows is arbitrary. In a `Grid` you need to specify each row definition.

If I could somehow have the `Grid`'s layout affect not only immediate children but nested ones, I think I could do this. I'm also willing to solve this with a different approach if you can think of one.

The expected finally behavior is a mixture of a `StackPanel` and a `Grid`, which is:

~ An arbitrary amount of elements can be added without defining rows (just stack them).

~ The container is divided into two columns for, first takes the size of the biggest element contained (auto), and the second takes the rest of the width available (*).

All help is welcome! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you considered using a ListView with a GridView, or a DataGrid?

Comment: I haven't. Can you show me an example?

Comment: There are *plenty* on the internet. Just search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to leverage [`ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup) and the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope) attached property. Try something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CSharpTest.RowControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="RowLabel"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And then to use it:

```
<mycontrols:ContainerControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
    <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
    <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
    <mycontrols:RowControl Label="Some label" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
</mycontrols:ContainerControl>
```

`mycontrols:ContainerControl` could be any type of container (e.g. `StackPanel`, `UniformGrid`, etc).

In the above, the first column of each `RowControl`'s `Grid` will be uniform (they will all grow to accomidate the largest `Label`). Depending on what's desired, you might also need to set `SharedSizeGroup` on the second column (to a *different* value, something like "RowText").

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this. This did it! Thanks, Keith :)